# Is there a way to calculate duration using xsd:dateTime in SWRL that pellet can reason with?

Tags: owl, swrl, pellet

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the duration of an interval when given two xsd:dateTime values.  Unfortunately, it seems that Pellet seems to only support 5 of the swrl builtins and none of the subtracting rules I've had luck with.  i.e. something like this:

```
hasStart(?x, ?xstart) ^ hasDuration(?x, ?xdur) ^ hasEnd(?x, ?xend) ^ inXSDDateTime(?xstart, ?xstartxsd) ^ inXSDDateTime(?xend, ?xendxsd) ^ swrlb:subtractDateTimesYieldingYearMonthDuration(?y, ?xendxsd, ?xstartxsd) -> hasXSDDuration(?xdur, ?y)
```

I haven't had much luck using the temporal library in SWRL either...